# jQuery-UI Sortable + nested sortable with connectWith

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Backbone.js + Require.js application. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="lists">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-cards">
      <div class="card">Foo</div>
      <div class="card">Bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-cards">
      <div class="card">Foo</div>
      <div class="card">Bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the lists sortable. And the cards across all lists sortable (within the list and from one list to another).

And the jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function() {

  $( '.lists' ).sortable({
    items: 'div.list'
  });

  $( '.list-cards' ).sortable({
    items: 'div.card',
    connectWith: '.list-cards'
  });

});
```

Backbone events array looks like this:

```
events: [
  'sortstart .lists': 'Foo',
  'sortstart .list-cards': 'Bar'
]
```

1. Problem: The events from .lists and .listcards disturb each other
2. Problem: When i disable cache (while DevTools is open) it works ironically, but i dont know why
3. Problem: Multiple events fire in Backbone events array when i sort a card

Question: Is there any elegant solution for this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How is this question a *RequireJS* question? I see nothing in the question that even suggests that RequireJS is an issue in the problem or a factor in solving it.

Comment: Even I am working on something similar like that. What I found was if I drop something on a nested sortable, the events of the parent sortable fire first. Hence they messep together.